# What makes a dialog displayable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I have a very simple dialog defined as:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class MyDialog{

  private String promptReply = null; // local variable to return the prompt reply value

  public String showAlert(String ignored, Context ctx)
  {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.promptdialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setTitle("Dialog Title");
    builder.setView(view);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (myActivity)ctx);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (myActivity)ctx);

    AlertDialog ad = builder.create();

    ad.show();
    return "dummystring";    
  }
}
```

And when I try to display it in `onCreate()` *after* calling `setContentView()` for the activity's main layout, the dialog simply doesn't show:

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.showAlert("Why isn't this shown???", this);
```

On the other hand, if I place the same exact call *before* calling `setContentView()` for the activity's main layout, the dialog shows just fine.

My question is why?

Why is the order critical in this case?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code to inflate view, use something like this:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.promptdialog,
                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
```

where `layout_root` is the  id of top level layout of your custom dialog.